# Replacing values in a data frame given a specified condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame as follows:

```
df->
ID TIME W
1   0   0.1
1   1   1
1   2   0.4
1   3   1.5
2   0   5 
2   5   0.3
```

I want to add a condition if `df$W >= 1` THEN put `zero` instead. How do I write that in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 df$W<-ifelse(df$W >= 1,0,df$W)
```

Comment: I used `Error in `df$W<-ifelse(df$W >= 1,0,df$W)` in the data frame that I have, it gave me an error: `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "W", value = logical(0)) :  replacement has 0 rows, data has 2500`

Comment: that error message looks like there is no column W in your dataframe where you are using the ifelse function on. Did you have the name of that column correct? upper-case W it must be if you use that exact function

Comment: You are right. I did a mistake. Thank you for pointing this out!